# DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE and DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE() difference?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

What is the difference between these two statements?

```
dbms_output.new_line(); // with no parameters.
dbms_output.new_line;    // with no parameters,no round brackets
```

If there is function overloading,even for that close and open brackets are required after function name.

Comment: For what version of Oracle?  The documentation for 9i doesn't list arguments as options - are you sure you aren't confusing `NEW_LINE('')` with `PUT_LINE`?  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_outpu2.htm#1000419

Comment: @Vineet can you even make a call such as : `dbms_output.new_line('')`?
new_line does not take any arguments?!?

Answer (score 4):

Well the difference is that the first formulation fails and the second one succeeds:

```
SQL> begin
  2      dbms_output.put_line('some text');
  3      dbms_output.put('about to new_line with no parameters');
  4      dbms_output.new_line;
  5  end;
  6  /
some text
about to new_line with no parameters

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> begin
  2      dbms_output.put_line('some text');
  3      dbms_output.put('about to new_line with a parameter');
  4      dbms_output.new_line('');
  5  end;
  6  /
    dbms_output.new_line('');
    *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'NEW_LINE'
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL>
```

**edit**

What does work is the empty brackets...

```
SQL> begin
  2      dbms_output.put_line('some text');
  3      dbms_output.put('about to new_line with a parameter');
  4      dbms_output.new_line();
  5  end;
  6  /
some text
about to new_line with a parameter

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I don't know when Oracle actually started supprting this convention but I only became aware of it when they introduced the OO stuff.  Some member functions (i.e. methods) on Types won't work unless we include the empty brackets e.g. XMLType's `getClobVal()`.  But the brackets are strictly optional for the standard procedural calls.

Comment: Your answer is right in context of this question what about
dbms_output.new_line();//it works same as dbms_ouput.new_line;
whats the differnce between them?

Comment: @Vineet: There is no difference between them, the brackets are optional when no parameter is provided.

Comment: Peter  ,you mean to say
 in pl/sql it is not necessary to give brackets after functions or procedures?

Comment: @Vineet: It is not necessary as long as they do not take any parameters. I prefer to always write the brackets anyway to improve readability. When defining functions or procedures without parameters, you cant' even use brackets: `CREATE PROCEDURE test() AS ...` won't compile.

Comment: @APC Why are we giving dbms_output.new_line  after dbms_output.put('about to new_line with no parameters'); ?
Without that it is coming in multiple lines.

Comment: @jobygeorge `put()` is a procedure for assembling a message out of text snippets. It does output anything to the screen until we issue a `new_line()` or a `put_line()`